# UISwipeGestureRecognizers won't be recognized simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my spritekit game, I am attempting to make it so that 2 UISwipeGestureRecognizers can be recognized simultaneously, however, I am unable to do so. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance. Below is my code...

In ViewDidLoad:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwiped1:)];

[leftSwipe1 setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[leftSwipe1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe1];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwiped1:)];

[rightSwipe1 setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[rightSwipe1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe1];
```

After ViewDidLoad:

```
-(void)rightSwiped1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

CGPoint pt = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
if(pt.x < (self.view.bounds.size.width/2))
{
    SKNode *person1 = [self childNodeWithName:@"person1"];
    SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 90, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200) duration:0.1f];
    [person1 runAction:moveRight];
} else if (pt.x > (self.view.bounds.size.width/2)) {

    SKNode *person2 = [self childNodeWithName:@"person2"];
    SKAction *moveRight2 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 400, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200) duration:0.1f];
    [person2 runAction:moveRight2];
}


}
-(void)leftSwiped1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
CGPoint pt = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
if(pt.x < (self.view.bounds.size.width/2))
{
    SKNode *person1 = [self childNodeWithName:@"person1"];
    SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 400, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200) duration:0.1f];
    [person1 runAction:moveLeft];
} else if (pt.x > (self.view.bounds.size.width/2)) {

    SKNode *person2 = [self childNodeWithName:@"person2"];
    SKAction *moveLeft2 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 90, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200) duration:0.1f];
    [person2 runAction:moveLeft2];
}
}
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer   shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by simultaneously. They never will be exactly in the same moment, as those are target-action based recognizers and the main UI Thread is serial. So there will be only one method firing at once.

If you mean there is a noticeable lag between the recognitions, you should try the solution of @originaluser2 and maybe experiment with `cancelsTouchesInView` or `delaysTouchesBegan` properties

Comment: I want both left and right swipe actions to occur at the same time if, how would i do that? If there is swiping on both sides of the screen at the exact same time, I want the designated action to take place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You never assign the `delegate` property of your `UISwipeGestureRecognizers`, therefore your delegate methods never get called.**

You can fix this by simply doing:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwiped1:)];

leftSwipe1.delegate = self;
[leftSwipe1 setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[leftSwipe1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe1];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwiped1:)];

rightSwipe1.delegate = self;
[rightSwipe1 setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[rightSwipe1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe1];
```

**Make sure you're also conforming to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol:**

```
@interface YourViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

...

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but for some reason both gestures are still not recognized simultaneously, I don't know what I'm doing wrong